# How to keep a text for longer duration on a screen in OpenCV?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am making an object detection application where once it spots a moving object, it puts a message on screen.But I want the message to stay longer on the screen.I tried doing something like this

```
while i < 10:
    cv2.putText(current_frame, "MOVING", (100, 300),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, 4, (255, 0, 0))
    i += 1
```

But it doesn't help and the text appears only for a second.How can I accomplish this?

Comment: That case you just put the text several times in the same frame, what you have to do is put a counter (starts with 0) and text variable(starts with "") outside the detecting loop. Every time you detect movement you put let's say 10 or 20 in the counter and the text to be shown, e.g. "Moving". before imshow, you do an if, that checks if counter is bigger than 0, if it is, do the puttext function and reduce the counter by 1.... This will show it for x amount of frames

Comment: @api55 that sounds like a plan!

Answer (score -1):

```
## the variable that store detected obj's positions and counters
locs = {}

## the loop 
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    ## your detection processing
    detectd, pos = detect(frame)

    ## Assume tag the obj on 5 frames
    if detectd：
        locs[pos] = 5

    for pos in locs:
        cv2.putText(current_frame, str(pos), loc, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, 4, (255, 0, 0))
    ## update the variable 
    locs = dict([(k,v-1) for (k,v) in locs.items() if v>0])
```

Comment: Are you sure the code syntaxes are correct because it shows the syntaxes are wrong.Beside I am using OpenCV 3.Maybe your code works for OpenCV 2?

Comment: You give nothing except the three lines. I express my idea in this code, though  not complete(the `detect` function is by yourself).